# Wake Lock in Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I am developing an app in which i need to send and receive packets in background. But I've discovered that when screen shut off also cpu and networking is disabled. So I've found on Android Developers that I should use wake lock and wifi lock to let the cpu works altought if the screen went off. This solution works for other devices such LG Optimus One but not for Samsung Galaxy Tab. With this device when screen shut off I can't receive no more packets (UDP) and magically when I press power button for re enabling screen, I restart to receive packets.
In my code I call:

```
powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_W AKE_LOCK, "TAG");
```

then

```
wakeLock.acquire();
```

I think that is a Samsung bug but I'm not sure of this, and if someone can give me some hint i would really appreciate.

P.S. I need some programming help... I already know that if I modify some manual setting to avoid shutting down the screen, this will work. But I'm developing an app and i need code!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` in your case.

I'm not sure why `SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK` is not enough (didn't find any documentation that justifies this), but `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` worked just fine for me in a similar scenario.

As another option you may use [`WifiLock`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html). But you need to be smart about that, as your network connection may be 2G or 3G, not Wi-Fi only. So you shouldn't hold Wi-Fi lock when you are actually using 3G/2G/etc.

Comment: Have you tried with Galaxy Tab?? because I tried this but when screen shut down I can only send and not receive.. PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK should keep CPU alive but in this case it seems that when screen shut down this doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, it works on Galaxy Tab (I've just re-checked). Why do you think this is Galaxy Tab specific?

Comment: Because with other devices I'm testing (LG Optimus One) it does work!! Also I'm checking but with PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK udp receiving doesn't work over wifi when screen is shut down.. I think this is a Samsung bug. Something like power saving function.

Comment: You should test your code on other samsung devices, see if you can repro your problem on them.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check the advanced WIFI settings.
In Preferences - WIFI settings, you can hit the menu key, click the advanced icon, and check the value for WIFI Sleep policy. One of the options is "When screen turns off".

Comment: In this preferences my checked options is "Never". Also I need a programming answer because I'm developing an app.